# Why didn't Class 1-A graduate after the finals?

Tags: my-hero-academia

When I finished Season 3 of the anime, I wondered why they were still class 1-A, and not 2-A. They took the finals in Season 2 and went to summer school in 3. At first I just thought they skipped over graduation. But then I started reading the manga, and they graduate a long time after (right after the villain arc if I remember). So why, if there is a reason, did they not graduate until then?

Comment: If you’re asking in general rather than specific to the anime or manga you don’t need the media tags. I know another user added the first but just as a general FYI.

Answer (score 5):

In *My Hero Academia*'s universe **school is based on the Japanese education system**:

> The academic year starts from April and ends in March, having summer vacation in August and winter vacation in the end of December to the beginning of January.
> <sub>(from the [*Education in Japan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_Japan) Wikipedia entry)</sub>

Episode S01E05 *"What I Can Do For Now"* shows Midoriya's first day at UA, and it's set in April:

[image: screenshot from S01E05, it's April]

<sub>(S01E05 minute 05:01, just after the episode title screen)</sub>

So, the summer vacation are not at the end of a school year, but in its middle instead; the "final" exams the students take in the last episodes of Season 2 are end-of-term tests.